# react waypoint onEnter call supress after first time

Tags: reactjs

In my OnEnter callback, I am making an api call to fetch more data. The data fetched is added to the array of elements I have. When I scroll back up, the api call is triggered again as the component is back in the viewport.

Is there a way to get around this?

[react waypoint](https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint)

code sample:
Okay, let me clean that  up a little bit: @jmeas

```
fetchData(props){  function to call the api with server side pagination
    if(props.previousPosition != 'above') {   //an attempt to check if we passed that waypoint, do not call the api again
      this.setState({page: this.state.page + 1}, function () {  //increment the page number
        this.getCatalogItems(this.state.categoryId, this.state.page) //make api call with incremented page number
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("fetched more data with scroll", res) //results
          })
      })
    }else{

      console.log("not calling fetch data")
    }
  }
```

This is how I am calling the waypoint:

```
class ProductContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("catalog product container initialized", this.props);
  }



  render() {

   const {catalogProducts, getCatalogItems, renderWaypoint} = this.props;

    console.log("props in roduct container", this.props)
    return (
      <div className="products-container">
              {
                catalogProducts && catalogProducts['products'] ?
                  catalogProducts['products'].map((product) => {
                  return (
                    <span>
                      HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
                    <CatalogProduct product={product}/>

                      </span>
                  )
                })
                  :
                  false
              }
              {renderWaypoint()}

              ########################################################################### way point here ################################################
        </div>

    );
  }
}

ProductContainer.propTypes = {
  catalogProducts: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  getCatalogItems: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  renderWaypoint: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};



export default ProductContainer;
```

What I want to do:

I have an infinite scroll catalog page. I wish to make the api call when user has scrolled  down to the waypoint which as in the component above is after we have rendered the products returned from first api call and would like to make another round trip to the server and render

Answer (score 0):

Without reviewing any code of your code... It seems as though you could just create flag and set it to true once the data has been loaded, then just check that flag before you load the data. Perhaps not the most elegant way, but it'll work.

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.data = [];
        this.fetched = [];
        this._loadPageContent = this._loadPageContent.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Waypoint
                key={cursor}
                onEnter={this._loadPageContent(this.props.pageId)}
            />
        );
    }


    _loadPageContent(i) {
        if(this.fetched.indexOf(i) <= -1){
            //go get the data
            this.data.push(someApiCall());
            this.fetched.push(i);
        }
    }
}

export default SomeClass;
```

Comment: It is the same api call to which I just pass the pageNumber I need to fetch data for. While I make the api call, I just increment the page number

Comment: I think if I'm understanding what you're saying, you're passing the page number to your load function ... so perhaps my updated code block helps?